# How to use x264 source code after compiling it

Tags: video-streaming, x264, libx264

I need to use the x264 code to compress and stream video from a camera in real time as part of my university project (first using computer and then dsp kit) (and vary quantization value when required). I am totally new to this domain and have absolutely no background.

So far I have compiled the code using the given method in http://www.ayobamiadewole.com/Blog/How-to-build-x264-or-libx264.dll-in-Windows and created the x264.exe and libx264.dll

I need help with what to do next in order to use the code for my purpose.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: EXE variant is for command line use ("x264 [options] -o outfile infile" - see `-help` for details), DLL is the one you link your code to, and use functions calls, `x264_picture_init` and friends.

Comment: @RomanR. could you please give me a link to a tutorial?